# Can't disable IntelliJ Inspector "Unused declaration" inspection type

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm running IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.4 Ultimate under the 30 day trial.

I have many many public methods in classes that aren't presently being called and I don't want the "unused declaration" to be searched for during inspections.

I've disabled it by unchecking it in the inspections preferences and re-run the inspector, but it still finds these problems.  I've re-enabled it and re-disabled it and re-run the inspector mandy times.  I've tried restarting intellij too.

Is there another setting I need to switch off to disable these, or is this a bug?  Can anybody else turn this off with this version?

Comment: It works for me under the `Declaration redundancy` header. Perhaps you are saving this under the wrong Inspection profile ? Try applying the profile and running it for the current file using Analyze -> Inspect Code

Comment: Yea I'm changing the right profile.  I confirmed by disabling it in all profiles and it's still picking them up.

Comment: One way to be certain is to turn the inspection level to a compilation error. If the java code still compiles you should create a bug report with Jet brains. On my IDE setting the inspection levels on the `Project Default` profile changed the warning immediately.

Comment: I added this issue with jetbrains: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-128837

Comment: Not a solution, but it might help you as a workaround: disable a custom style for unused references: IDE Settings -> Editor -> Color & Fonts -> General -> Unused Symbol -> Remove all styles on the right

Comment: This was resolved in IntelliJ 14, but not in Android Studio, yet. See: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-114413